# System Configuration and date time missing

Tags: 12.04

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 fully updated.
Date is missing in unity top panel.

When I go to System Configuration, it does not work.
Also, I can not change my wallpaper because System Configuration does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I had this problem too - THANK YOU so much for providing the answer! I have one thing to add - my time settings did not take effect immediately; the system configuration became available but the time settings were grayed out until I rebooted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this trouble once before. For me, my package `gnome-control-center` was uninstalled. Go into terminal and run `sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center`. If it is uninstalled, install it. If it is installed, let me know and I can try to find another answer.

For the missing date-time install the package `indicator-datetime`.

Comment: [user137933](http://askubuntu.com/users/137933/user137933) has pointed out that it may be necessary to reboot to apply the changes: "my time settings did not take effect immediately; the system configuration became available but the time settings were grayed out until I rebooted."