# After 13.04 upgrade system apps are missing (settings, displays)

Tags: 13.04, system-settings

I've upgraded to 13.04 and some things are missing. I can neither open the system settings nor the "displays" app to change dual monitor settings.

When I click on "System Settings..." in the top right corner nothing happens. And on the top right there's no more date/time shown, I presume I could change that in the settings.

How do I get the "Systems Settings" and "Displays" app back? I can't find the right packages.

[image: missing settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my...I found a [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122043/system-configuration-and-date-time-missing) and ran the following

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-control-center is already the newest version.
gnome-control-center set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

(See how nothing was installed)

Both "System Settings" and "Displays" are there now.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, Ubuntu 18.04LTS. since some days, (since update gnome?) , I cannot use Settings, cannot find it anymore on my system.

I did re-install Settings with command

sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center

and after installation: Settings is back in Show Applications and is running normally