# Time and date and appearance settings missing

Tags: settings

I am a Linux user since 2010. I used Debian, elementary OS (which is also Ubuntu) and now I'm using a fresh install of Ubuntu itself.

But I'm already having some problems that I can't find how to solve. The first of them is that there are some missing settings on my configurations. See:

[image]

I can't see the wallpaper settings, screensaver or date and time settings. I can set wallpaper by right-clicking an image and then clicking on "Set as wallpaper". No way to set screensaver. I can set the date from the terminal, but I can't show to my personal friends how amazing Linux is and encourage them to change to it, if even to set the clock they must see me going to terminal. If I click the date and then click 'Date and time settings', it just shows up the configurations panel (from image above). Also, I work with different timezones, and I want to see many timezones when I click the date in topbar, which is not being possible.

I couldn't find another topic with exactly the same problem...

Comment: Maybe http://askubuntu.com/q/122043/158442?

Comment: Didn't work, I already have gnome-control-center and indicator-datetime packages installed.

Comment: Which flavour is it? Kubuntu?

Comment: It is 'stock' Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: Try reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` then. A few posts suggest this, but I'm not sure what it does to fix this. `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!
http://postimg.org/image/8yg5yx501/
However it should be a standard reply, so I could select it as correct answer :P
I've been searching for the fix for many other topics and forums, and didn't find it in any of them.

Comment: What did it do? I'm curious.

Comment: (i edited the previous comment)
Installing ubuntu-desktop and restarting it solved, now I have appearance and time/date settings :D

Comment: I got it from http://askubuntu.com/questions/466720/system-settings-icons-missing-in-14-04, so I'll mark as a duplicate.